# Pure CSS to color sibling span

Tags: html, css

I am trying to change the color of a span based on the title of a separate span in another div.

The following is working as expected, the second span with text2 is colored red.

```css
span[title=Red] ~ span {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<span title="Red">text1</span>
<span >text2</span>
```

If the spans are in separate divs as per the below, note there are additonal attributes in case these are needed to make the selection.

Text2 is no longer colored red. What am I missing?

```css
#form .formField span[title=Red] ~ #form .formField span {
    color:Red;
}
```

```html
<div id="form">
    <div class="formField" customId="abc">
        <span title="Red">text1</span>
    </div>
    <div class="formField" customId="xyz">
         <span>text2</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `~` doesn't work that way

Comment: Css general sibling selector `~` only applies on the children of the same parent element.

Comment: @JoshuaOoi Siblings, not children

Comment: my bad. typed wrongly hahahaha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do what you want to do, you'd need to use the newer [`:has()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has) pseudo-class to look down the DOM and apply the styling you want. In your second example, `#form .formField span[title=Red] ~ #form .formField span`, `~` won't work because you're trying to select `#form` as if it were a sibling of the `span` with the title, which it's not.

```css
#form:has(.formField span[title=Red]) div.formField~div.formField span {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="form">
  <div class="formField" customId="abc">
    <span title="Red">text1</span>
  </div>
  <div class="formField" customId="xyz">
    <span>text2</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you @j08691! I wasn't aware of :has()

Answer (score 0):

You can just set a normal class.

```
<!-- css -->
.red {
 color: red;
}

<!-- html -->
<div id="form">
 <div class="formField" customId="abc">
  <span class="red" title="Red">text1</span>
 </div>
<div class="formField" customId="xyz">
 <span>text2</span>
</div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jasonbruce/n953ufxL/